# Change the position of a Google Maps control?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When using the Google Maps API, you can set the position of a control like this.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.643387, 153.612224),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    }
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I would like to set the position depending on user screen. I have a varible isMobile and tried to configure the position like this:

```
  position: (isMobile)?google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER:position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
```

But this did not work. Are there other ways to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `position: isMobile?google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax has an error, you are trying to add `position` twice.
Try it like this:

```
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition[isMobile?'BOTTOM_CENTER':'TOP_CENTER']
}
```